# Define backround color of an activity for android device with API level 28

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have created an application for my android device with android version 10 (API Level 29). It works fine. But now I want to use this app also on a device with android version 9 (API Level 28). It also works, but the backround color of my activities which I have defined in File styles.xml (res->values->styles.xml) is completely black instead of nearly white (#F5F5F5) like I have defined it in the snippet below:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#F5F5F5</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

I´m sure the problem is, that the API Level can not work with the line:
`<item name="android:windowBackground">#F5F5F5</item>`

It doesn´t matter which color I define in this line, the backround color stays always black. I have testet also an compiler for devices with API Level 28, but the compiler can not compile exactly this line.
Does anybody know, which code-line I can use instead of this, so it runs also for devices with API level 28? Thank you...

Comment: check if the target device is in Dark Mode or not, I think the color is changing for the dark mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this inside the root layout of the concerned activity

```
android:background="#F5F5F5"
```